# How to display align div?

Tags: css

How change my code to create new classes: title and body from div-table-col with align property inside?
Header must be moved to right and Test must be moved to the left.

```css
      .div-table { 
        display: table; 
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: #eee; 
        border: 1px solid #666666; 
        border-spacing: 5px; }
        
      .div-table-row { display: table-row; width: auto; clear: both; }

      .div-table-col { float: left;  display: table-column; width: 50%; background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col" align="right">
       Header: 
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col" align="left" padding-left="5px">
        Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to create:

```css
          .div-table { 
            display: table; 
            width: 100%; 
            background-color: #eee; 
            border: 1px solid #666666; 
            border-spacing: 5px; }
            
          .title { display: table-row; width: auto; clear: both; align:right}

          .data { float: left;  display: table-column; width: 50%; background-color: #ccc; align:left     padding-left:5px}
```

but it does't works. It displaies properly now, but I would like to remove align property and padding-left and move it to styles.

Comment: “Header must be moved to right and Test must be moved to the left.” They are already aligned that way. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if I understand what you want, but if the only thing is Header on the right and Test on the left you need to make an other float, becasue you're applying the same float to both of them.

```css
.div-table { 
        display: table; 
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: #eee; 
        border: 1px solid #666666; 
        border-spacing: 5px; }
        
      .div-table-row { display: table-row; width: auto; clear: both; }

      .div-table-col2 { float: left;  display: table-column; width: 50%; background-color: #ccc; }
      
      .div-table-col { float: right;  display: table-column; width: 50%; background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col" align="right">
       Header: 
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col2" align="left" padding-left="5px">
        Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```